# Como puedo ejecutar una Funcion por Clases

Tags: javascript, jquery

Un gusto. Les explico, tengo un Codigo que se encarga de subir una Imagen y esta se previsualiza.

```
                             <center>
                                  <div class="col-md-4" >
                                  <div class="form-group drag-drop">
                                    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="foto[]" id="foto1" class="inputFoto form-control" required>
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-2x span1" id="span1">
                                        <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-stack-2x bottom pulsating"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x top medium"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up fa-stack-1x top"></i>
                                      </span>
                                      <span class="fa-stack fa-2x span2" id="span2"style="display:none;">
                                      <img id="imagenPrevisualizacion1"  style="width: 128px;height: 128px; z-index: 3px;margin-top: -0.5em;margin-left: -1em; margin-top:-50%;" class="imgFoto">
                                      </span>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </center>
                                    <div class="col-md-2" ></div>
                                <center>
                                  <div class="col-md-4" ><div class="form-group drag-drop">
                                    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="foto[]" id="foto2" class="inputFoto form-control" required>
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-2x span1" id="span3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-stack-2x bottom pulsating"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x top medium"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up fa-stack-1x top"></i>
                                      </span>
                                      <span class="fa-stack fa-2x span2" id="span4"style="display:none;">
                                      <img id="imagenPrevisualizacion2"  style="width: 128px;height: 128px;z-index: 3px;margin-top: -0.5em;margin-left: -1em; margin-top:-50%;" class="imgFoto">
                                      </span>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </center>
```

Este es el trozo del Formulario.

El Problema se presenta al momento que se clona estos campos, debido a que estas imagenes van con un Input indicando un Alias. Quise hacer el Codigo Dinamico por clases para no hacerlo por ID, pero me arroja error.

```
 var inputFoto = document.getElementsByClassName("inputFoto").length,
    imgFoto = document.getElementsByClassName("imgFoto").length,
    span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("span1").length,
    span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("span2").length;

for (var i = 0; i < inputFoto.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    // Escuchar cuando cambie
    inputFoto[i].addEventListener("change", () => {
        // Los archivos seleccionados, pueden ser muchos o uno
        const archivos = this.files;
        // Si no hay archivos salimos de la función y quitamos la imagen
        if (!archivos || !archivos.length) {
            imgFoto[i].src = "";
            return;
        }

        // Ahora tomamos el primer archivo, el cual vamos a previsualizar
        const primerArchivo = archivos[0];
        // Lo convertimos a un objeto de tipo objectURL
        const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(primerArchivo);
        // Y a la fuente de la imagen le ponemos el objectURL
        imgFoto[i].src = objectURL;
        //Cambiamos los Estados de los Span
        span1[i].style.display = "none";
        span2[i].style.display = "inline-block";
        console.log("Finalizado");
    });
}
```

Error: Uncaught TypeError: imgFoto[i] is undefined.

Antes cuando no era requerido el que se clonara estos campos lo tenia de esta manera:

```
const $seleccionArchivos = document.querySelector("#foto1"),
    $imagenPrevisualizacion = document.querySelector(
        "#imagenPrevisualizacion1"
    );

$seleccionArchivos.addEventListener("change", () => {
    // Los archivos seleccionados, pueden ser muchos o uno
    const archivos = $seleccionArchivos.files;
    // Si no hay archivos salimos de la función y quitamos la imagen
    if (!archivos || !archivos.length) {
        $imagenPrevisualizacion.src = "";
        return;
    }
    // Ahora tomamos el primer archivo, el cual vamos a previsualizar
    const primerArchivo = archivos[0];
    // Lo convertimos a un objeto de tipo objectURL
    const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(primerArchivo);
    // Y a la fuente de la imagen le ponemos el objectURL
    $imagenPrevisualizacion.src = objectURL;
    //Cambiamos los Estados de los Span
    document.getElementById("span1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("span2").style.display = "inline-block";
});
```

Funcionaba Bien. Gracias de Antemano
PD: Antes tenia que repetir el Codigo en caso de que se requiriera más de una foto. Mi Idea es que funcione sin necesidad de repetir codigo o estar asignando dinamicamente un ID. Si pueden darme una mejor opción es bienvenido :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que obtener todos los campos tipo `file` con [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) y se puede hacer por nombre del campo, sin tener que usar ID's dinámicos ni clases.

Después recorres la colección HTML obtenida para asignar evento a cada uno. Este evento se dispara solo cuando se selecciona un archivo nuevo, no hay forma de eliminarlo, a menos que se haga un `reset` del formulario, pero eso es para otro tema y solo se necesitaría validar que el archivo seleccionado sea una imagen, suponiendo que el usuario modificó directamente los campos.

Dentro de la función que maneja el evento usas `e.target` para identificar el campo que se modificó; usando [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) seleccionas el contenedor padre de campo e imagen y, desde ahí, obtienes la imagen.

Revisa los comentarios para ver lo que se hace en cada paso.

```js
// Obtener todos los campos por nombre
let fotos = document.querySelectorAll('[name="foto[]"]');
// Recorrer para asignar evento
fotos.forEach(foto => foto.addEventListener('change', fotoPreview));
// Función para ejecutar cuando se modifique un campo, recibe evento como parámetro
function fotoPreview(e) {
    // Seleccionar campo que disparó el evento
    let foto = e.target;
    // Crear código para establecer como fuente de imagen
    let imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    // Obtener contenedor común entre campo e imagen por clase
    let parent = foto.closest('.form-group.drag-drop');
    // Obtener imagen desde el contenedor padre
    let image = parent.querySelector('.imgFoto');
    // Asignar fuente de imagen
    image.src = imageUrl;
}
```

```html
<center>
    <div class="col-md-4" >
        <div class="form-group drag-drop">
            <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="foto[]" class="form-control" required>
            <span class="fa-stack fa-2x span1" id="span1">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-stack-2x bottom pulsating"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x top medium"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up fa-stack-1x top"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="fa-stack fa-2x span2" id="span2">
                <img class="imgFoto" style="width: 128px;height: 128px;">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
<div class="col-md-2" ></div>
<center>
    <div class="col-md-4" >
        <div class="form-group drag-drop">
            <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="foto[]" class="form-control" required>
            <span class="fa-stack fa-2x span1" id="span1">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-stack-2x bottom pulsating"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x top medium"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up fa-stack-1x top"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="fa-stack fa-2x span2" id="span2">
                <img class="imgFoto" style="width: 128px;height: 128px;">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
<div class="col-md-2" ></div>
```

**Nota:** Quité estilos que modifican atributos de la imagen (o su contenedor) para que puedas ver que todo funciona correctamente.

Comment: Gracias! Me sirvio perfecto.